# code signing error in iphone

Tags: iphone, sign

i had the following error when try install my app to the device.The log is as follows

```
CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/Ponshoppe.app
cd "/sumeet/Iphone projects/Ponshoppe"
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Sumeet Soni (N8AKMK8BFV)" "--resource-rules=/sumeet/Iphone projects/Ponshoppe/build/Debug-iphoneos/Ponshoppe.app/ResourceRules.plist" --entitlements "/sumeet/Iphone projects/Ponshoppe/build/Ponshoppe.build/Debug-iphoneos/Ponshoppe.build/Ponshoppe.xcent" "/sumeet/Iphone projects/Ponshoppe/build/Debug-iphoneos/Ponshoppe.app"

/sumeet/Iphone projects/Ponshoppe/build/Debug-iphoneos/Ponshoppe.app: The operation was cancelled by the user.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks in advance .......

Comment: The error message says: *The operation was cancelled by the user.* So, did you get some dialog and have pressed cancel or something ?

Comment: no. nothing appears.But i tried to export the private key and press deny in the end to cancel the export.

Comment: hi that post i ve deleted to bcz haven't get the better answers...u can answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323482/store-userid-from-facebook-sdk … man graph code u gave me works fine..but it gives me :`getMeButtonPressed:  {"id":"100004560969","name":"A B","first_name":"A","last_name":"B","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/A.B.94064","username":"A.B.94064","gender":"male","timezone":5.5,"locale":"en_GB","verified":true,"updated_time":"2012-10-21T20:30:24+0000"}`

Comment: is it possible if i fetch only id or username... you can reply on my post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restart the mac , it will solve the problem.This works for me.....