# Store UserID From Facebook SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, uiwebview

How can I store credentials in the Facebook iOS SDK atleast username if not password. I gone through the Facebook iOS SDK ...FBSession which is been need to use login part.but its a Library file ..I cannot see the implementation part .which is

```
[[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView

                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,

                                      FBSessionState state,

                                      NSError *error)
```

Is it possible to keep credentials? or to hacking a UIWebView to load the facebook login page without showing it to the user and inject the credentials if that is possible at all.

Comment: there is only one single way to fulfill your need is to check your FBgraph methods where it makes request to login through webview , i tink there you can extract username or password

Comment: @Aman ya thanks..that works but stuck on this  ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354191/facebook-ios-sdk-3-0-8-crash-xcode-on-alternative-login